# Video card structure - SLI or 2 separate cards?

Tags: video, graphics-card, sli

I have a 27 inch screen I'm using for gaming and 2x 25 inch screens I won't use for games.  I currently have a `GeForce GTX 460` and it only supports 2 monitors.  I need to get my 3rd monitor up and running.  I'm debating between going SLI or 2 separate cards.  Do enough games support video on all 3 screens to where I should just go the route of SLI for the heck of it?  Right now I mainly play SC2, but you never know in the future...

Comment: You just asked almost the same question here: http://superuser.com/questions/562631/what-does-sli-ready-mean-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [How can I play games on a triple monitor setup using my Nvidia graphics card?](http://superuser.com/questions/315056/how-can-i-play-games-on-a-triple-monitor-setup-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card) and [What is the best way to enable the use of triple monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/299246/what-is-the-best-way-to-enable-the-use-of-triple-monitors).

Comment: @Breakthrough He's taking the information he is given and then rewriting a question around that.

Answer (score 0):

You gamers generally go with SLI configurations. However if you are going to buy a video card that does not have the same GPU as the GTX - 460 they will not work in SLI. To read more about SLI I'd look into [this](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/469402/sli/faq-quot-will-these-two-cards-work-in-sli-quot-sli-what-works-with-what-/).